# Any Reason why someone can open PDF Attachment in Classic, but cannot open the same attachment in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-experience, attachment, pdf, insufficient-privileges

There is a PDF attachment on a custom object, this is opening fine in Classic​  but in Lightning​  it throws **Insufficient Privileges** error (in a classic window) as below when user tries to view it. **Note this happens for Admin user.**

> **Insufficient Privileges** You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the
>   owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For
>   more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

[image]

This PDF attachment is created from a managed package, but as far as I can see there is no access issue. Appreciate any help to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the app is throwing an exception?  I know normal users can see this screen in that case, I'm not sure if the same can apply for Admins when it's a managed package.

Comment: Hi @IllusiveBrian thanks, this error is thrown when we just view the PDF from the attachments related list. App is not throwing any exceptions.

Comment: Can you show the full URL?

Comment: Do they have a license to the app?

Comment: Hi @bigassforce, Eric Thanks guys, this looks little bit strange, We doubt it's because Salesforce migration of Attachments to Files. When we upload a file in classic, we cannot view in Lightning (Any PDF file) and giving above error screen (Lightning related list via View All shows no file-size for the pdf files added from classic), when we upload a pdf file to attachments in Lightning it can be viewed in both Lightning and classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was experienced while accessing a cusomer org using LMO. But this was not there when they (customer) directly accessed the org.

Also we suspected it's due to Salesforce migrating from Attachments to Files. We advised users to go with Files than Attachments in the future.

Also in dev, we changed code to create Files instead Attachments.